# make the animation last forever

Tags: html, css

I want to create a button that will change the background color and the text color when the pointer cursor moves into the button but I'm stuck on how to make the animation last as long as the cursor is still in the button block instead of keeping on flickering. This is my button:hover code:

```
.button:hover{ 
  animation-name: heading1;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: forward;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the CSS property called [infinite](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can share you animation, it would be helpful. but if you want a single iteration then you can try this

```
:hover{ 
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: forward;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to change the background-color and color upon hover so this might be of some help

// transition just makes it more smooth

```
button {
  transition: 0.5s; 
}



button:hover {
   background-color: red;
  color: cyan;
}
```

this should help you out

Answer (score -1):

I think you are going at this the wrong way. This is how you can create a button that changes background and text color on hover.

```css
a.button {
  /* default colors */
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: blue;
  
  /* transition effect and duration for only background and font color */
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s linear, color 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s linear, color 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s linear, color 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s linear, color 0.3s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.3s linear, color 0.3s linear;
  
  /* button style */
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

a.button:hover {
  /* changes button colors on hover */
  background-color: blue;
  color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Button</a>
```

NOTE: The extra transitions aren't necessary, but they will make sure that the effect will show correctly on all supported browsers.